# Qt QLinkedList object append issue

Tags: c++, qt, object, linked-list

I have this code:

```
QLinkedList<Usuario*> conectados;
Usuario *jose = new Usuario("Jose",1,1234);

conectados << jose;
conectados << new Usuario("Prueba2",1,123);
conectados << new Usuario("Prueba3",1,123);

QLinkedList<Usuario*>::iterator iterator;
for(iterator = conectados.begin(); iterator != conectados.end(); iterator++)
{
  qDebug()<< (*iterator)->getUserName();
}
```

And this output:

"Prueba3" 
"Prueba3" 
"Prueba3"

I tried with QLinkedList, a linkedlist without pointers, but with the same result. I dont know what Im doing wrong. I believe that I appending the same pointer to the linkedlist, or overwriting  the same object.

Thanks for the help. Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took your snippet of code and filled in the blanks.  I don't see any problems here - it must be in your accessor method, getUserName();

```
class Usuario
{
public:

  Usuario(const QString name, int value1, int value2) : m_Name(name) {}

  QString getUserName() {
    return m_Name;
  }

private:
  QString m_Name;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  QLinkedList<Usuario*> conectados;
  Usuario *jose = new Usuario("Jose",1,1234);

  conectados << jose;
  conectados << new Usuario("Prueba2",1,123);
  conectados << new Usuario("Prueba3",1,123);

  QLinkedList<Usuario*>::iterator iterator;
  for(iterator = conectados.begin(); iterator != conectados.end(); iterator++)
  {
    qDebug()<< (*iterator)->getUserName();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
"Jose" 
"Prueba2" 
"Prueba3"
```

Comment: The problem wasnt in the accessor method, Its in the statement of the variables, Im doing it as Im programming on C, at the top of Usuario.cpp and not in the usuario.h file, in the private section.

Thanks for you help =).